# How to call/invoke fsc, the F# compiler, from FAKE?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

How do I tell FAKE to compile a `.fs` file using `fsc`?

Bonus points for explaining how to also pass arguments like `-a` and `-target:dll`.

EDIT: I should clarify that I'm trying to do this *without* having an MSBuild/xbuild/`.sln` file. In other words, I want FAKE to fully take the place of MSBuild/xbuild.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FAKE has tasks to directly invoke the F# compiler. Usually you can use the `Fsc` task. If you want a target to compile an F# source file `MyFile.fs` to `MyFile.exe`, you can do:

```
Target "MyFile.exe" (fun _ ->
  ["MyFile.fs"]
  |> Fsc (fun ps -> ps))
```

The `Fsc` task lets you compile multiple source files and specify every F# compile parameter. This simple example doesn't do that, but you can. To read up on the details, head over to [the tutorial](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/fsc.html).

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you read [Ian Battersby's page](http://blog.ianbattersby.com/2012/08/04/passing-build-properties-with-fake-fsharp-make/) on FAKE make on this topic

Code Excerpt:

first:

```
#!/bin/bash
TARGET=$1
BUILDTARGETS=$2

if [ -z "$BUILDTARGETS" ]
    then
                BUILDTARGETS="/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Libraries/mono/xbuild/Microsoft/VisualStudio/v9.0"
fi

if [ -z "$TARGET" ]
    then
    CTARGET="Default"
else
    CTARGET=`echo ${TARGET:0:1} | tr "[:lower:]" "[:upper:]"``echo ${TARGET:1} | tr "[:upper:]" "[:lower:]"`
fi

if [ ! -d "$BUILDTARGETS" ]
    then
    echo "BuildTargets directory '${BUILDTARGETS}' does not exist."
    exit $?
else
    export BUILDTARGETS="$BUILDTARGETS"
fi

echo "Executing command: $CTARGET"

mono packages/FAKE.1.64.6/tools/Fake.exe build.fsx target=$CTARGET
```

then

```
#I @"packages/FAKE.1.64.6/tools"
#r "FakeLib.dll"
open Fake

let buildDir = @"./build/"
let testDir = @"./test"

let fxReferences = !! @"*/*.csproj"
let testReferences = !! @"Tests/**/*.csproj"
let buildTargets = environVarOrDefault "BUILDTARGETS" ""

Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDirs [buildDir; testDir]
)

Target "Build" (fun _ ->
    MSBuild buildDir "Build" ["Configuration","Debug"; "VSToolsPath",buildTargets] fxReferences
        |> Log "Build-Output: "
)

Target "BuildTest" (fun _ ->
    MSBuildRelease testDir "Build" testReferences
        |> Log "Test-Output: "
)

Target "Test" (fun _ ->
    !! (testDir  + @"/*.Tests.dll")
        |> xUnit (fun p ->
            { p with
                ShadowCopy = true;
                HtmlOutput = true;
                XmlOutput = true;
                OutputDir = testDir })
)

"Clean"
  ==> "Build"

"Build"
  ==> "BuildTest"

Target "Default" DoNothing

RunParameterTargetOrDefault "target" "Default"
```

Comment: Thanks Rachel. I may be thick-headed, but am not being able to understand how to apply this technique to actually invoke `fsc` raw, without having an MSBuild/xbuild file (or `.sln` file). So I rolled my own....

Answer (score 1):

Here's a possibly-useful -- though admittedly small -- twist on Yawar's answer above, which might make it fit in a bit better with the other FAKE examples you're likely to encounter.

The `Fsc` helper function wants a string list of filenames, which is fine as far as it goes.  But most examples use the `!!` operator to find files, which results in `FileIncludes` which happens not to be a string list.  You can convert a `FileIncludes` to a string list suitable for feeding to `Fsc` with `Seq.toList`.

Just to be thorough, I also convert things to relative pathnames (possibly just a personal quirk).

So here's an example of searching for all `*.fs` files and compiling them with some representative compiler options:

```
Target "BuildApp" (fun _ ->                            // Compile application source code
  !! (srcApp @@ @"**/*.fs")                            // Look for F# source files
    |> Seq.map toRelativePath                          // Pathnames relative to current directory
    |> Seq.toList                                      // Convert FileIncludes to string list
    |> Fsc (fun p ->                                   //  which is what the Fsc task wants
      {p with                                          // Fsc parameters: making an executable, 
         FscTarget   = Exe                             //  for any CPU, directing output to build 
         Platform    = AnyCpu                          //  area (both assembly & XML doc).
         Output      = ...exe file...                  // Executable generated
         OtherParams = ["--doc:" + ...xmldoc file...) ]})
)                                                      //
```

As Yawar pointed out, there are a boatload of other compiler options covered in [the tutorial](http://fsharp.github.io/FAKE/fsc.html).